# Правильно ли сформулирована такая фраза?

Tags: лексика

Правильно ли сформулирована эта фраза?

> 8 новых лайфхаков из детства.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На мой взгляд, "новые лайфхаки из детства" - это оксюморон.
Лайфхаки либо новые, либо "из детства" (т.е. заведомо старые).

Если это первый или единственный материал на эту тему, слово "новых" лучше опустить:

> 8 лайфхаков из детства.

Если же вы уже писали про лайфхаки из детства, и теперь хотите подчеркнуть, что речь идет о какой-то новой подборке на эту же тему, то лучше сформулировать это так:

> Новые 8 лайфхаков из детства.

Comment: На мой взгляд, все словосочетание не верно. Ведь понятие "лайфхак" в детстве и не было.

Comment: @Серж, Мне кажется, здесь сознательно обыгрывается то, что знакомые нам с детства полезные советы теперь начинают свою вторую жизнь в статусе "лайфхаков".

Comment: Возможно, вы и правы. Здесь игра слов. Но насколько удачна — не знаю.

Answer (score 0):

Зависит от контекста и того, что вы хотите сказать. Если где-то есть серия статей, где вспоминаются лайфхаки, которыми люди пользовались в детстве, то новая статья на эту тему вполне может так называться.